# Support sections on the bookmark in landscape mode

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, sectioning, bookmarks, landscape

I'm writing a book and I want to put a unnumbered chapter (`chapter*`), where I will discuss the results and then put the results in tables. These results are divided into three options, so I want to make a section for each option (again not numbered `section*`) and their respective table. Each table contains 15 columns and about 150 rows. For the amount of columns and rows I put it in `landscape` mode and use the `longtable`.

The problem is that when compiling the file.tex in file.pdf doesn't place the names of the sections  in the pages; and the links in the `tableofcontents` and `bookmark` aren't made in the page that must also be.

**tables are long, so I work with external files (tables.tex)**

MWE

```
\documentclass{book} 
...
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage[pdftex,pdfpagelayout=SinglePage]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
....
\bookmark[page=3,level=0]{Contents}
\tableofcontents
....
\chapter*{Results}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Results}
Discussion of results ....

\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}

\section*{tabla1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{table1}
\input{./table1.tex}
\pagebreak

\section*{tabla2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{table1}
\input{./table2.tex} 
\pagebreak 

\section*{tabla3} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{table1}
\input{./table3.tex}

\end{center}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `fancyhdr` [package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

It will not only provide you with the possibility to have chapter, page number, section name, etc. on each page, but will also be fully compatible with the package you are loading (specially for cross referencing like `hyperref` and `bookmark`).

It is also very easy to use, and can be set with just a few commands (See the package documentation in the link above for more information).

Now, please bear in mind that by using the `landscape` environment you will always have a `\newpage`, so the `section` title won't be on it.  Nevertheless, as mentioned before, you can set a header using `fancyhdr` where you can have the name of the section displayed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer @Mario S. E. I will read the package documentation.